# FF not changing css in attr properly

Tags: jquery

I have the following attr set for when the browser resizes, but firefox only recognizes position: absolute, but not the left property as well. In Chrome it is normal.

JQuery:

```
jQuery('.quick-access').attr('style', 'position:absolute; left: -100px !important');
```

It simply wont change the left position, but Chrome will.

Any ideas?

Also, it needs to be inline, because it has some inline rules to begin with.

EDIT:

I tried also with .css method but it is not applying.

```
       jQuery('.quick-access').css({
            'position' : 'absolute',
            'left' : '-100px !important'
       });
```

I tried taking out !important but it doesnt work anyway.

Comment: Can you post your html, or create a jsFiddle so we can have a look at a live example :-)

Comment: Also, why not use the `css` method instead?

Comment: Cant post fiddle, as I am working on a live site which is quite messed up as it is. In the same rule I have css also but it wasn't applying, I added !important but it didn't work. I will edit now with that code.

Comment: This works for me in Firefox: http://jsfiddle.net/ne4sS/

Comment: @roasted I came to the same conclusion... we are obviously missing something

Comment: @BenCarey We need a link where we can see this strange behaviour as there is no direct reason this is not working on FF

Comment: @undefined removing !important for left declaration fix this issue, but why? Isn't !important supported by .css() jquery method?  http://jsfiddle.net/q36jk/2/

Comment: @undefined  You cannot specify `!important` in the way you have in your jsFiddle! It works if you do this: http://jsfiddle.net/q36jk/1/

Comment: Thank you for all the answers. Adding a new css class worked in this case, but I will also upvote all other helpful answers. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you are using the `attr()` method for a specific reason, it would be easier to just use the jQuery `css()` method like so:

```
$('.quick-access').css({
    position: 'absolute',
    left: -100
});
```

**You cannot specify `!important` using the jQuery `css()` method, or any method to my knowledge...**

**UPDATE**

Another way to achieve what you would like is to simply add/change the `class` of the element in question (.quick-access).

You can do this like so:

```
$('.quick-access').addClass('newStyles');
```

And then you can set `newStyles` to override the original styles:

```
.newStyles {
    position: absolute;
    left: -100px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`!important` doesn't work in the jquery this way .... i will recommend you make a class with that style and add class using `addClass`

here is how you can do -

css -

```
.offset {
  position : absolute;
  left : -100px !important;
}
```

js -

```
jQuery('.quick-access').addClass('offset');
```

Comment: Why downvote? Because as i can test it, this answer seems accurate

Comment: i don't know who downvoted,altleast someone should tell in comments whats wrong

Comment: Surely because this should be a comment not an answer, i guess

Comment: may be but i thought i am giving the solution about using class, anyway thanks :D

Comment: @RohitAgrawal Downvote wasn't me, but maybe you should post some code as an example, otherwise, as roasted mentioned, this is more suited as a comment...

Comment: i will take care next time

Comment: @RohitAgrawal No need to take care next time, your advice was good, just back it up with some examples. All help is appreciated on SO, but you have to show that you have made an effort :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this using [.offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/):

```
jQuery('.quick-access').offset({ left: -100 });
```